# How can I read a tsv file with irregular line break

Tags: python-3.x, csv

how to read data file with rows of different length?
I'm trying to load a tsv(tab separated) file, each line should include 19 attributes. But some lines have 4 attributes, and the next line has others. 
Each record has all 19 attributes, they just have an irregular line break.
How to deal with this file? I want to store them in a table as a dataset, then I can use iloc to get a suitable list.

I ran this code, but get the error
"Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 32770, saw 19"

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('data1.tsv',sep="\t",header=None)
T = dataset.iloc[:,8].values
```

the file just like:

```
(line1)1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
(line2)1 2 3 4 
(line3)5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
(line4)1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
...
```

Comment: This is weird. What is more commons is that newline are embedded into fields which can exhibit the problem. But in that case, the correct way of solving it is to control where the csv file contains quoting or escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, but .. my code is really ugly

```py
    import csv
    with open('data1.tsv',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    dataset=[]
    tmp=[]
    for row in spamreader:
        if len(row)==19:
            dataset.append(row)
        elif len(row)==4:
            tmp=row
        elif len(row)==15:
            tmp.extend(row)
            dataset.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
```